# Grouped Bar Chart From JSON D3.JS

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Got the bars to show up and graph looks as expected, except the bars are stacking on each other for each month instead of spread out over the area. They just keep overwriting each other for each month.

My D3.keys(data) Returns 1,2,3,4,5 instead of the thought 1-2015,1-2016,etc.

Again everything is working, just the bars are all starting in the corner of the month. So each month is getting a stack of bars overwriting each other instead of being grouped next to each other?

**UPDATE**

My data is not always uniformed, this is proving to make this very dificult. Some months a result wont be there, instead of having a "Maple: 0" some months Maple just simply wont be there. So making this chart have any sort of color grouping is beyond me.

With the data i have provided i would like to make a grouped bar chart as so http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051
with the months in place of states and all possible materials for each month the bars inside the months. The legend would need to color code to the same colors as the bars, however due to the problem above i dont see that possible with this data. What i need to do is check for all possible materials over all months, then insert a 0 and that material to all months that dont have it.  However how to do this with D3 is beyond me.

I really wish the D3 examples would have more nested JSON examples, the examples are all run on very simple formated CSV files, these dont help with real world examples!

My Code (JSON BELOW)

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40,},
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([height, 0]);

        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x0)
          .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(y)
          .orient("left")
          .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var data = nestedData;

        var months = d3.keys(data);

        x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
        x1.domain(months).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.values, function (d) { return d.values;}); })]);

       svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

       svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Boxes");

       var month = svg.selectAll(".month")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.key) + ",0)"; });

        month.selectAll("rect")
          .data(function(d) {return d.values; })
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.values); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.values); })
          .style("fill", "red");
```

JSON Data

```
[
  {
    "key": "1-2015",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "MDF",
        "values": 726
      },
      {
        "key": "MAPLE PAINT GRADE",
        "values": 1652
      },
      {
        "key": "ALDER",
        "values": 1922
      },
      {
        "key": "MAPLE",
        "values": 1206
      },
      {
        "key": "ALDER - RUSTIC",
        "values": 324
      },
      {
        "key": "POPLAR-MDF",
        "values": 19
      },
      {
        "key": "POPLAR STAIN GRADE",
        "values": 679
      },
      {
        "key": "OAK",
        "values": 12
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "4-2015",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "MAPLE",
        "values": 1979
      },
      {
        "key": "MAPLE PAINT GRADE",
        "values": 1988
      },
      {
        "key": "ALDER",
        "values": 1746
      },
      {
        "key": "MDF",
        "values": 883
      },
      {
        "key": "POPLAR STAIN GRADE",
        "values": 639
      },
      {
        "key": "OAK",
        "values": 89
      },
      {
        "key": "POPLAR-MDF",
        "values": 24
      },
      {
        "key": "ALDER - RUSTIC",
        "values": 367
      },
      {
        "key": "HICKORY",
        "values": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "WALNUT",
        "values": 20
      },
      {
        "key": "CHERRY",
        "values": 0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "2-2015",
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "MAPLE PAINT GRADE",
        "values": 1758
      },
      {
        "key": "ALDER",
        "values": 1551
      },
      {
        "key": "ALDER - RUSTIC",
        "values": 339
      },
      {
        "key": "MDF",
        "values": 727
      },
      {
        "key": "MAPLE",
        "values": 1712
      },
      {
        "key": "POPLAR STAIN GRADE",
        "values": 434
      },
      {
        "key": "POPLAR-MDF",
        "values": 16
      },
      {
        "key": "OAK",
        "values": 12
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What've you tried so far? Or is this more of a 'not even sure where to start' sort of thing?

Comment: Not even sure where to start, everything I've seen has been using data in a Different format, more of a one object per record and not multiple objects like i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
.attr("widht", x1.rangeBand())
```

Correcting that, I get a [chart that seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/tx9p93se/).

Comment: This makes the chart show up! However now my problem is the with X1  itself.. The bars are all on top of each other instead of splitting up across the month.

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you mean. Did you want them stacked vertically, or grouped next to each other?

Comment: My problem is each month does not have to have the same materials, so i almost need to get a list of all the possible materials (inner keys) and make a new array with Month/All possible arrays, then pass this to D3..  Im so lost haha